# Rails remote true form submitting form multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

Using `remote:true` in rails form for submission.
But issue I am facing is that sometimes its submitting form multiple times .

I read somewhere that its may be due to `// = require jquery_ujs`

application.js

```
// = require v1/jquery-2.1.1.min
// = require jquery_ujs
// = require v1/spritespin.min
// = require v1/slick.min
// = require v1/bootstrap.min
// = require v1/bootstrap-editable.min
// = require turbolinks
```

Rails version is 4.2.10

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: It could also be turbolinks, try disabling it and see iff the issue still happens

Comment: @maxpleaner is it possible to fix with use turbolinks

Answer (score -1):

From the [API](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag), if you use `submit_tag`, or `button_tag` (You can read [api](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/button_tag)). By default user cannot submit form twice.

However, it's good idea for your users in this case to add a 'waiting' status if user hit submit button

```
submit_tag "Complete sale", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }
button_tag "Complete sale", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }
```

The other way, you can prevent this behavior in your controller. So, in case your user has slow internet, they hit button twice, its okay to perform `js response` again but you do nothing to your DB if the data already found

Comment: same issue even after adding disable_with: